# KerasClassifier object has no attribute model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm using `CalibratedClassifierCV` to calibrate the probabilities of my CNN model. I'm using the following code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
def load_model(*args, **kwargs):
    path="my_model.hd5"
    model = load_model(path)
    return model

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=load_model)
calib = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv='prefit', method='sigmoid')
calib.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When using this code I'm getting the error message `AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model'`. Also when I use `clf.predict(X_test)` I'm getting the same error. So something seems to be wrong with `KerasClassifier`.

Is there a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefined keras' `load_model` function (`from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model`) with a namesake (`def load_model(*args, **kwargs)`) - that may be the problem.